# Syntax error defining a template function

Tags: c++, templates

Just starting to learn templates in C++ and I have a small piece of code that's not compiling:

```
template <class gen_data>
{
    gen_data calculate(gen_data a, gen_data b)
    {
        return a+b;
    } 
}

int main()
{
    int c,d;
    cout<<"The sum is: "<<calculate(c,d)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled it it gave me an error

> in function main 'calculate' was not declared in that scope

Can anyone help explain where this error comes from?

Answer (score 4):

You have the wrong syntax for declaring a template function. There shouldn't be braces surrounding the `calculate` function. Try rewriting it like this:

```
template <class gen_data> gen_data calculate(gen_data a, gen_data b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have one pair of braces too many. This worked for me:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class gen_data>
gen_data calculate(gen_data a, gen_data b) {
 return a+b;
}

int main() {
 int c = 1, d = 2;
 std::cout<<"The sum is: "<<calculate(c,d)<<std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```